# Google Authenticator in php

Tags: php

Im using a google authenticator package from https://github.com/PHPGangsta/GoogleAuthenticator.

I'm pretty confused as to how the verifyCode function works since it gives me a success output no matter if the code generated is entered correctly or wrongly. Could someone explain how to validate the generated code from user?

This is my code:

PHP

```
$ga = new PHPGangsta_GoogleAuthenticator();
$secret = $ga->createSecret();
echo "Secret is: ".$secret."\n\n";
echo '<img src="' . $ga->getQRCodeGoogleUrl('BeautyStyle', $secret) . '">';
$oneCode = $ga->getCode($secret);
echo "Checking Code '$oneCode' and Secret '$secret':\n";

$checkResult = $ga->verifyCode($secret, $oneCode, 2);    // 2 = 2*30sec clock tolerance

if(isset($_POST['verify']))
{
    if ($checkResult) 
    {
        echo 'Success';
    }    
    else 
        {
        echo 'FAILED';
        echo $userinput;
        }
}
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<table cellspacing="3px">
<tr>
<td><input required class="formfield" type="text" name="verifycode" placeholder="Code"></td></tr>
</table>

<div class="signupbutton">
<input type="submit" name="verify" value="Sign Up">         
</div></form>
```